# django error: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'siteerrors'

Tags: django

I'm getting this strange error in my logs.  Instead of getting a stacktrace in my browser, I'm getting an internal server error.

Is this an app I need to install in my settings?

Here is the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'siteerrors'

Answer (score 0):

I guess i have an app that is called siteerrors.  I added it and the error went away.